# Strange behaviour with ConnectionFactory using CDI with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi, c3p0

I have this class (my database connection factory):

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private ComboPooledDataSource datasource;

    private Long open = 0l;
    private Long close = 0l;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException {
        datasource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        datasource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql:dbcampanha");
        datasource.setUser("postgres");
        datasource.setPassword("admin");

        datasource.setMinPoolSize(1);
        datasource.setMaxPoolSize(5);

        datasource.setCheckoutTimeout(30000);
        datasource.setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(30);
        datasource.setMaxIdleTime(30);

        datasource.setDebugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces(true);

        datasource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        open++;

        try {
            Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {          
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void close(@Disposes Connection connection) {
        close++;

        try {
            connection.commit();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Long getOpenedConnectionCounter() {
        return open;
    }

    public Long getClosedConnectionCounter(){
        return close;
    }

    public ComboPooledDataSource getDatasource(){
        return datasource;
    }

}
```

I use this class with an JAX-RS application. And for some tests using this route:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/test")
public class TesteService {

    @Inject
    private Connection connection;

    @GET
    @Produces(MyMediaType.JSON)
    @Path("/yes")
    public Response success() throws SQLException {
        connection.getClientInfo("");

        return Response.ok().build();
    }

}
```

And this class for my Client:

```
public class TesteMain {

    private static final String prefix = "http://localhost:8080/schoolwork/service/test/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Request request = new Request(prefix + "yes");
            request.start();

            if(i % 10 == 0)
                Thread.sleep(1000l);
        }
    }

    public static class Request extends Thread {

        private String rota;

        public Request(String rota){
            this.rota = rota;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection url = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(rota).openConnection());
                url.connect();

                System.out.println(url.getResponseCode() == 200 ? "SUCCESS" : "ERROR");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I receive this infos:

```
{
  "opened-connection": 789,
  "closed-connection": 867,
}
```

Yes, I have a number of closed database connection greater than opened. HOW? Any idea for this?

**I use**

Tomcat 7 + Java 7

P.S. I am sorry for my bad English :/

**SOLVED**

I change my counters for AtomicInteger objects, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

So, two quick comments:

1. Your counters are (boxed) longs read and updated willy-nilly by 1000 concurrent Threads. Their values will in general be unpredictable and nondeterministic. They certainly won't accurately count what you intend them to count. Consider using atomic operations on AtomicLongs instead.
2. Your `commit()` (or `rollback()`) should be attached to your database business logic, the part where you can tell a unit of work has either succeeded or failed. You shouldn't automatically commit on close.

Comment: I have some bussiness exceptions throught my system. When i catch one of this exceptions i call `rollback`. If not catch any bussiness exceptions i call commit();

Comment: you call commit() in any case prior to close(). perhaps you will have just rolled back so the commit will be a no op if something failed. it is still bad hygiene though, i think. commit() should be an affirmative confirmation that everything has succeeded. you've made it the default, and require other logic to signal failure (and to never ever do any work after that signal of failure). Another issue with your commit/close logic is that it is a Connection leak. Exceptions on commit will cause close() to be skipped, which will eventually exhaust your Connection pool.

Comment: To be safe, Connection open should occur within a try block and close in that same block's finally. you are relying on injection of a Connection, so you won't do that, but you'd better be sure that there's no possible Exception or code path that would cause the call the close() to be skipped.